# Неявное преобразование c shared_from_this()?

Tags: c++, boost

Есть пример [отсюда](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp) и вот часть кода из него :

```
class chat_participant
{
public:
  virtual ~chat_participant() {}
  virtual void deliver(const chat_message& msg) = 0;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<chat_participant> chat_participant_ptr;

class chat_room
{
public:
  void join(chat_participant_ptr participant)
  {
    participants_.insert(participant);
    std::for_each(recent_msgs_.begin(), recent_msgs_.end(),
        boost::bind(&chat_participant::deliver, participant, _1));
  }

private:
  std::set<chat_participant_ptr> participants_;
  enum { max_recent_msgs = 100 };
  chat_message_queue recent_msgs_;
};

class chat_session
  : public chat_participant,
    public boost::enable_shared_from_this<chat_session>
{
public:
  chat_session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, chat_room& room)
    : socket_(io_service),
      room_(room)
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
    room_.join(shared_from_this());
```

Так вот, что происходит в строчке с `room_.join(shared_from_this());`? У метода join тип `shared_ptr<chat_participant>`, а `shared_from_this()` в той строчке  вернет объект с типом `shared_ptr<chat_session>`. Если я правильно понял, то зачем это и как работает?

Comment: А что конкретно зачем это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит неявное преобразование chat_session* к chat_participant*.

Функция-член chat_room::join более общая и не нуждается в конкретизации дочерним классом chat_session, то-есть ей достаточно базового класса chat_participant. В месте вызова этой функции компилятор и производит неявное преобразование к базовому классу.

Перефразируя Вас - в той же строчке только что возвращенный объект `shared_ptr<chat_session>` неявно преобразовывается к `shared_ptr<chat_participant>` который и передается в вызываемую функцию.

Comment: А как понимать не нуждается в конкретизации? А в каких случаях нуждается? Просто не силен в ООП.